# Evaluating $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n}{n^2+i^2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

A few days ago I confronted this limit question, and all my attempts to solve it failed somehow.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{n^2+i^2}
$$
I feel I should relate it to $\arctan(n)$. I tried integration and derivation to reach my point, it went well at first but eventually nowhere.

Any kind of help and enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: $0 < \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(n^2+i^2)} \le \frac{n+1}{n^2}$ by majorizing each term by the the first; can you conclude?

Comment: @Conrad you likely mean that we should bound below by the last term...

Comment: @gt not sure I understand your comment - each term is at most the first which is $1/n^2$ and since there are $n+1$ terms the sum is at most $\frac{n+1}{n^2} \to 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{n^2+i^2} = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=0}^n \frac 1 {1 + \left( \frac i n \right)^2} \cdot \frac 1 n = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=0}^n \arctan'\left( \tfrac i n \right)\cdot \tfrac 1 n
$$

That last sum is a Riemann sum that approximates $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \arctan'(x)\,dx = \arctan 1 - \arctan 0 = \frac \pi 4,$ but outside the sum there is a factor of $1/n$ that approaches $0,$ so **ultimately the limit is $0.$**

Comment: A Riemann sum goes from zero to $ n-1$  or from one to $ n$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah : And that will make no difference because that extra term at the end goes away as $n\,\to\,\infty. \qquad$

Comment: Yes, but it is not a Riemann sum as you said.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah : not sure why you dont consider that a Riemann sum or why the last term matters at all. can you give examples of the difference.

Comment: @jimjim A Riemann sum goes from $ 0$ to $n-1$ or from $ 1$ to $ n$. If you add a term which tends to zero, the limit of the sum does not change, but It is not a Riemann sum : It is a Riemann sum plus a certain term.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah : if the difference between two things is zero then they are the same thing. you can add infinitely many terms that sum of all them tends to zero and it is same as just the Riemann sum. if their difference is zero then they are the same thing, because a Riemann sum is same as Riemann sum plus  finitely many things that tend to zero, so I can say that Riemann sum is Riemann sum plus x terms that tend to zero. There is no difference, if there was then their difference wouldn't be 0.

Comment: You can then say that $ \frac 1n = 0$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah it depends on whether you are finding the left Riemann sum or the right Riemann sum

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah , Yes you can say that, as there is no $\epsilon \gt 0 $ s.t. $|\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon| \neq 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It was exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: but I don't understand one thing

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{0\le i\le n}{1\over n^2+i^2}
&={1\over n^2}+\sum_{1\le i\le n}{1\over n^2+i^2} \\
&={1\over n^2}+\int_{1-\varepsilon}^n \,{\mathrm d\lfloor t\rfloor\over n^2+t^2} \\
&={1\over n^2}+\left.{\lfloor t\rfloor\over n^2+t^2}\right|_{1-\varepsilon}^n-\int_1^n[t-\{t\}] \, \mathrm d\left(1\over n^2+t^2\right) \\
&={1\over n^2}+{1\over2n}-\int_1^nt \, \mathrm d\left(1\over n^2+t^2\right)+\int_1^n\{t\} \, \mathrm d\left(1\over n^2+t^2\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

wherein the integrals are evaluated as follows

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^nt \, \mathrm d\left(1\over n^2+t^2\right)
&=\left.{t\over n^2+t^2}\right|_1^n-\int_1^n \, {\mathrm dt\over n^2+t^2} \\
&={1\over2n}-{1\over n^2+1}-\left.{1\over n}\arctan\left(\frac tn\right)\right|_1^n \\
&={1\over2n}-{1\over n^2+1}-{\pi\over4n}+\frac1n\arctan\left(\frac1n\right) \\
&=\mathcal O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\int_1^n\{t\} \, \mathrm d\left(1\over n^2+t^2\right)=\mathcal O\left(\frac1n\right)
$$

As a result, we have

$$
\sum_{0\le i\le n}{1\over n^2+i^2}=\mathcal O \left(\frac1n\right)
$$

Comment: unfortunately, numerical method is not what I'm looking for. but thanks.

Comment: @hypatia But this isn't a "numerical method." It's a Riemann-Stieltjes integration that provides an asymptotic expansion.